# clicking on the anchor link tab is opening new window in IE8 and works fine in Mozilla and FF

Tags: html

I have written a below code for tabbed anchor links

```
<div class="tabBox" >
    <div class="tabArea">
        <a class="tab activeTab" href="#" target="dV" onClick="changeIt('dV'); 
        <a class="tab activeTab" href="#" target="dV" onClick="changeIt('dV'); return false">tab1</a>
        <a class="tab" href="#" target="ugf"  onClick="changeIt('ugf'); return false">tab2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabMain" STYLE="width:400">
    <span ID="dV"></span>
    <span ID="ugf"></span>
</div>
```

When we click on the tab1 or tab2 in IE8 it is opening a new window. But in FF and chrome it is showing in the tab data in the same window. Why it is opening a new window in IE8

Comment: Achieved 200% readability improvement by splitting up the code over several lines. Currently it's invalid HTML though, you might want to correct this.

Comment: You should also include the javascript code of the "changeIt" function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using the [target attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.3) incorrectly. If it's not one of the four [reserved target names](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.16), it *specifies the name of a frame where a document is to be opened*.

If removing the attribute doesn't resolve your problem, you will have to show us the `changeIt()` function.
BTW if you've set an XHTML doctype you shouldn't use `onclick` camelcased.